# Integration of contentful sdk

Tags: ios, contentful

How to integrate contentful sdk to my swift project.I don't know how to do this.I use pod for installing contentfulDeliveryAPI but I was stuck with that because all code I founded was objective c.I don't know objective c and I'm a new iOS developer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no strictly Swift specific documentation, but an example project that shows how to integrate and use the SDK from Swift. You can find that [on Github](https://github.com/contentful-labs/Swiftful).

Comment: Sadly to say.This is not helpful :(